# What view to use to override Orchard Content Menu Item

Tags: razor, content-management-system, orchardcms

I have added "Content Menu Item" to the navigation in my Orchard Site.  I also customized MenuItemLink.cshtml to do what i need.

The MenuItemLink changes work on menu items that link to a page but they do not run for "Content Menu Item"s that I add.

Where do I add customization for "Content Menu Items"?

Thanks for helping a rookie.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thrag, just had this issue myself and found an answer.  Create an alternate named MenuItemLink-ContentMenuItem.cshtml and copy your override in there also.  Hope this helps